# height does not seem to work properly on Chrome 77

Tags: html, css

I have a page that works fine with Firefox but not with Chrome 77.

```css
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightblue, rgb(61, 133, 214));
}

#main-section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/15/1000/1000");/* any image you want */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#main-section-background {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.main-content {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightblue, rgb(61, 133, 214));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
  </header>

  <section id="main-section">
    <div id="main-section-background">
      <div class="main-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Background image opacity works fine with Firefox. With chrome, the height and min-height properties do not have any effect and opacity is not visible.
I tried several ways to force the height of the content but it looks like Chrome is applying the opacity only on the actual HTML content (not put here for clarity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize your code and keep only the `main-section` where you apply multiple background:

```css
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightblue, rgb(61, 133, 214));
}

#main-section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.9),rgba(255,255,255,0.9)),
    url("https://picsum.photos/id/15/1000/1000");/* any image you want */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightblue, rgb(61, 133, 214));
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
  </header>

  <section id="main-section">
    
  </section>

  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: That works ! I was convinced that I needed 2 div to manage opacity.